# Pagination Links

Tags: solspace-tag

We are using [pagination_links](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/pagination.html#pagination-links) throughout a site and would like for the tag page to match. I'm wondering if there's a way to get pagination_links to work with Tag? I tried simply adding "tag_" to all the variables, but that did not work.

This is the pagination_links code we are using:

```
{paginate}
  {pagination_links page_padding="5"}
<hr>
    <ul class="pagination">  
      {first_page}
        <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
         {/first_page}

         {previous_page}
           <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
         {/previous_page}

        {page}
          <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
         {/page}

         {next_page}
           <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
         {/next_page}

        {last_page}
          <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
         {/last_page}
       </ul>
<hr>
    {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which template tag are you using? Tag:Entries? If so, just prepend the {paginate} and {pagination_links} variable pairs with **tag_**, and no others (Re: [Docs](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#tag_paginate)).

Your final solution would look like this:

```
{tag_paginate}
   {tag_pagination_links page_padding="5"}
      <ul class="pagination">  
         {first_page}
            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-first">First Page</a></li>
         {/first_page}
         {previous_page}
            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-previous">Previous Page</a></li>
         {/previous_page}
         {page}
            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-{pagination_page_number} {if current_page}active{/if}">{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
         {/page}
         {next_page}
            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-next">Next Page</a></li>
         {/next_page}
         {last_page}
            <li><a href="{pagination_url}" class="page-last">Last Page</a></li>
         {/last_page}
      </ul>
   {/tag_pagination_links}
{/tag_paginate}
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. I'll try and read more closely next time (I need a vacation).

Comment: Hmm... I thought it was working, anyway. Using that code within the tag:entries tag, this is what is rendering on the page: `{tag_pagination_links page_padding="5"}
    {first_page}
    First Page
    {/first_page} {e2c518d61874f2d4a14bbfb9087a7c2dprevious_page}
    Previous Page
    {/e2c518d61874f2d4a14bbfb9087a7c2dprevious_page} {page}
    {pagination_page_number}
    {/page} {e2c518d61874f2d4a14bbfb9087a7c2dnext_page}
    Next Page
    {/e2c518d61874f2d4a14bbfb9087a7c2dnext_page} {last_page}
    Last Page
    {/last_page} 
{/pagination_links} `

Comment: It likely does not accept advanced parameters like "page_padding". Try removing that and see if it parses. :)